# How do I make an unsigned 8 bit adder in VHDL ? And an unsigned 8 bit subtractor?

Tags: vhdl

How do I make an unsigned 8 bit adder in VHDL ? And an unsigned 8 bit subtractor  ?

I am having trouble with the unsigned.

The name of the file is adder1.vhd.

I attempt to synthesize it using Design Compiler.

Code is here:

```
-------------------------------------------------
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
--USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
------------------------------------------------
ENTITY signed_adder IS
PORT (a, b: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
sum: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0));
END ENTITY;
------------------------------------------------
ARCHITECTURE arch OF signed_adder IS
SIGNAL a_sig, b_sig: UNSIGNED(3 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
a_sig <= UNSIGNED(a);
b_sig <= UNSIGNED(b);
sum <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(a_sig + b_sig);
END ARCHITECTURE;
```

Design Compiler gives me the error....

```
Error: Cannot find the design 'adder1' in the library 'WORK'. (LBR-0)
0
if { ! $ok } {
  echo "ERROR: elaboration failed"
  exit 1
}
ERROR: elaboration failed
```

Again, the name is the file compiled is adder1.vhd.

So why is Design Compiler giving me this error ?

Comment: Typically you'd use language built-ins for this, and let the synthesizer optimally target any ultimate hardware platform.  If that's not an option for you, then this is presumably homework, and homework requires that you show some meaningful effort.  Such an assignment won't have come from nowhere, there will have been preceding classwork, lecture notes, etc.  There's also a lack of clarity as to exactly what sort of manual implementation should be performed - explicit gates?  Algebraic expression?

Comment: I made one but it is not synthesizing in design compiler.

Comment: Edit your attempt and the error message *as text* into your question

Comment: ok i did that above

Comment: It doesn't seem like the code you posted corresponds to the error, are you mixing different attempts or leaving something out?

Comment: The name is the file with the code is adder1.vhd and that is what design compiler is complaining about which is why i am confused.

Comment: try to give your entity the same name as your file, so either rename the entity to `adder1` oder the file to `signed_adder.vhdl`.  Further, notice that you have a lot of length mismatches in your code. The internal signals should have the same length as the inputs and the sum needs to be 1 bit longer than the longest input as you may have an overflow otherwise.

Comment: Matching the names did it - thanks !  I feel so dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness, answer is already in the comments

An entity of a VHDL component has to match the filename. Therefore you should either rename the entity to `adder1` or the file to `signed_adder.vhdl`.

As mentioned there are other potential issues in your code

```
a_sig <= UNSIGNED(a);
```

The compiler should complain here because you try to assign an 8bit vector to a 4bit vector. Your internal signal `a_sig` should have the same size as your input. Another thing is that when you add two 8bit numbers, the result might be 9bits long. Therefore your `sum` should be of type `std_logic_vector(8 downto 0)`.

And as a side note, there's no benefit of adding the internal signals in your case. Technically you could directly do

```
sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) + unsigned(b))
```